# Passing an argument to a function of class from C# using ironpython.

Tags: c#, python-3.x, ironpython

NET programming and I don't know how to pass an argument from .NET to a class function in python script supported by ironpython

Here is my .cs script.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;

using IronPython.Hosting;

namespace PrintToConsole
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What would you like to print from python?");
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            var py = Python.CreateEngine();
            //var scope = py.CreateScope();
            //scope.SetVariable("x", input);
            try
            {

                //py.Execute("print('From Python: %s'%x)");
                 py.Execute("import x" );
                 py.Execute("s=x.operation()");
                 py.Execute("sum=s.add(input)");
                 py.Execute("print(sum)");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                "Oops! We couldn't print your message because of an exception: " + ex.Message);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my corresponding python script.
        import sys

```
class operation():
    def __init__(self):
        self.y=int(input('enter a no :'))
    def add(self,x):
        sum=sys.argv[1]+self.y
        return(sum)
```

Also, Can I send the images using the same technique?
Thanks in advance!